# Exporting all tableau sheets into one PDF using tabcmd script

Tags: tableau-desktop

I am trying to export all sheets (tabs) in Tableau Workbook into one PDF file. I read the documentation and it is possible to do it. However, I want to create each PDF for different parameter values. What I want works when I export only one view using the desired parameter but when I export the entire workbook into PDF, the parameters get ignored.

this gives me entire workbook into PDF but paramters are ignored

`tabcmd export /NeedsAssessmentforHEIStrategicPlanning/PlanningAndImplementationTeams?Parameters.HEI=WUS --fullpdf --filename "D:\exports\tetk.pdf"`

this gives me just one sheet exported into PDF and the parameter selection is NOT ignored.

`tabcmd export /NeedsAssessmentforHEIStrategicPlanning/PlanningAndImplementationTeams?Parameters.HEI=WUS --pdf --filename "D:\exports\tetk.pdf"`

The difference is the use of `--fullpdf` to export the entire workbook and `--pdf` to export just one view

What am I doing wrong? Here is the documentation: [https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/tabcmd_cmd.htm#id7cb8d032-a4ff-43da-9990-15bdfe64bcd0](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 0):

can you please try this format:

```
tabcmd export "workbookname" --pdf -f "filename.pdf"
```

In your case:

```
tabcmd export "/NeedsAssessmentforHEIStrategicPlanning/PlanningAndImplementationTeams?Parameters.HEI=WUS" --pdf --f "D:\exports\tetk.pdf"
```

assuming this D drive is in your Tableau server

Comment: Hello @debayan! Thank you but this only generates the filtered view of one worksheet only, namely "Planning and Implementation Teams". What I want is a filtered view of all worksheets that exist in this dashboard? For this reason, I was using `--fullpdf` option, which does export all sheets into one PDF but does not create a filtered view.